# Script add exception to IE popup blocker

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Looking for other suggestion or a way to script adding an exception to the IE popup blocker.
Here is the situation.

We have a domain MyDomain.com that is where our core SP2010 site sites. Then we have 2 other domains that direct to other applications within our organization. ie site1.MyDomain.com and site2.MyDomain.com. We have a page in the SP2010 site that loads an iframe containing a table of contents page from site1.MyDomain.com. clicking one of the links will popup a window with detail information from site1.MyDomain.com for your selection. Then links on that popup page takes you to site2.MyDomain.com. The problem is that if the user has their popup blocker enabled and has their banner notification turned off then they are not notified that a popup was triggered.

I would like to be able to run a script on the home page of the SP2010 page to detect if *.MyDomain.com has been added to the popup blocker exclusion list if not then prompt the to add the site. I don't know if it's possible but any feed back would be greatly appreciated. We are looking for a solution that would consider the end user to be a blathering idiot and still have this work. You know how marketers business requirements are.

Comment: And why doesn't your organization add these in by default with the OS image or a group policy?

Comment: The internal users do not have this problem because they are GPO's to take care of the problem. We are having issues with external users not on the network.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clear. This is a public facing website accessible to all users that have a login ID for the system.